# How bind function inline Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would bind my function directly when declaring my function, the following attempt fails:

```
(function f() {
  return this.a;
}).bind({a: 'qwerty'});


var g = f()    
console.log("g: ", g)
```

how achieve this result?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an assignment of the bound function. [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function.

```js
var f = function () {
        return this.a;
    }.bind({ a: 'qwerty' }),
    g = f()    

console.log("g:", g);
```